# bootstrap typeahead.js deletes content of existing data in html form-field onLeave

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using typeahead in a form that already has data. The problem is: When I enter and then leave the field without typing anything, it is emptied by typeahead.

Form-Element:

```
<span class="twitter-typeahead">
  <input class="form-control tt-hint" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"  type="text">
  <input name="myfield_name" id="myfield_name" class="form-control tt-input" placeholder="Dateneingabe" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">

  <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none; right: auto;">
     <div class="tt-dataset-5">
     </div>
  </span>
</span>
```

Source:

```
 randomtime = new Date().getTime();

    var suggest_specimen_name = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
         return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.suggestname); 
         },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      limit: 10,
      prefetch: {
        url: 'json_suggestioncreator.php?spam='+randomtime
      }
    });

    suggest_specimen_name.initialize();

    // instantiate the typeahead UI
    $('#myfield_name').typeahead(null, {
      displayKey: 'suggestname',
      source: suggest_specimen_name.ttAdapter()
    });
```